# Tk inter not showing if statement in gui window

Tags: python

hi i have the following definition set up as a program that allows me to calculate a certain amount from entered figures :

```
def racun() :
number = float(sladkor2.get())
number2 = moka2.get()
number2 = float(number2)
number3 = margarina2.get()
number3 = float(number3)

koliko_tort = (number // sladkor)
koliko_tort2 = (number2 // moka)
koliko_tort3 = (number3 // margarina)

if 1 <= koliko_tort <= koliko_tort2 <= koliko_tort3:
    (print("Kolicina moznih tort je:", int(koliko_tort)))
elif 1 <= koliko_tort3 <= koliko_tort <= koliko_tort2:
    (print("Kolicina moznih tort je:", int(koliko_tort3)))
elif 1 <= koliko_tort2 <= koliko_tort3 <= koliko_tort:
    (print("Kolicina moznih tort je:", int(koliko_tort2)))
elif 1 <= koliko_tort3 <= koliko_tort2 <= koliko_tort :
    (print("Kolicina moznih tort je:", int(koliko_tort3)))
elif 1 <= koliko_tort <= koliko_tort3 <= koliko_tort2:
    (print("Kolicina moznih tort je:", int(koliko_tort)))
elif 1 <= koliko_tort2 <= koliko_tort <= koliko_tort3:
    (print("Kolicina moznih tort je:", int(koliko_tort2)))
else:
    (print("Iz danih kolicin ni mozno narediti nobene torte."))
return
```

The problem i face is that entered values for variable koliko_tort, koliko_tort2 and 3 if print() do not show in the gui window setup below:

```
mGui = Tk()
sladkor2 = StringVar()
moka2 = StringVar()
margarina2 = StringVar()

mGui.geometry('500x500')

mGui.title('Domaca naloga')
mLabel = Label(text ='Naloga 1', fg= 'brown')
mLabel.pack()

mLabel2 = Label(text = 'Vnesite poljubno kolicino sladkorja v kg:', fg='black').pack()

mEntry = Entry(textvariable = sladkor2).pack()

mLabel3 = Label(text = 'Vnesite poljubno kolicino moke v kg:',     fg='black').pack()

mEntry2 = Entry(textvariable = moka2).pack()

mLabel4 = Label(text = 'Vnesite poljubno kolicino margarine v kg:', fg='black').pack()
mEntry3 = Entry(textvariable = margarina2).pack()

mButton = Button(mGui,text='Naprej', command = racun).pack()
mGui.mainloop()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `print()` does not send anything to the Tkinter GUI.  You'll need to send that information to a widget or a stringvar being displayed by a widget.

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem, but you must not `pack` a widget and assign it to a variable on the same line. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get) for more information.

Comment: no the program works, everything works great, except for the fact that variable that is supposed to be under  `koliko_tort` etc. is now shown in the python window but not on gui. I get that my `print` option here is wrong for this, i just sadly have no idea how to formulate a correct command for that.

Comment: `label_where_text_should_go.config(text="string you want to display goes here")`.

Comment: Em, `label_where_text_should_go.config`, that is the var with which is set up a label prior to this? So e..g. label1 = Label?